# ActionScript 3, How to get character to jump for longer

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I am making a platformer game in Flash (AS3) and the code I have below works. I want my character to jump high enough to allow it time to reach a platform. The only problem with code below is the speed at which it jumps up and down and the height of the jump. Tthe space bar is what triggers the function to run.

Please help as I would much appreciate it! :)

```
Player.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fl_MoveInDirectionOfKey);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, fl_SetKeyPressed);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, fl_UnsetKeyPressed);

function fl_MoveInDirectionOfKey(event:Event)
{
    if (spacePressed){
        var gravity:Number = 9.8;
        var jumping:Boolean = false;
        var jumpVar:Number = 0;

        if(jumping != true)
        {
            jumpVar = -70;
            jumping = true;
        }

        if(jumping)
        {
            spacePressed = false;
            Player.y += jumpVar;
            jumpVar += gravity;
        }
        Player.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, drop);
        function drop(event:Event)
        {
            Player.y -= jumpVar;
            jumpVar -= gravity;
            if(Player.y > 350){
                Player.y = 350;
            }
        }
        Player.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fl_MoveInDirectionOfKey);
        Player.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fl_MoveInDirectionOfKey);

        /*var frameNumb:Number = 0;

        Player.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, jumpup);
        spacePressed = false;
        function jumpup(event:Event)
        {
            while(frameNumb < 30){
                spacePressed = false;
                Player.y -= 1;
                frameNumb += 0.5;
            }
            Player.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, jumpup);
            Player.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, jumpdown);
            function jumpdown(){
                while(frameNumb > 0){
                    spacePressed = false;
                    Player.y += 1;
                    frameNumb -= 0.5;
                }
            }
        }*/
    }
    if (leftPressed)
    {
        Player.x -= speed;
        Player.gotoAndStop("left");
    }
    if (rightPressed)
    {
        Player.x += speed;
        Player.gotoAndStop("right");
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your use of 9.8 for gravity is meters-per-second-per-second.  Since drop() is executed every frame, you're going to get some serious fast-forward gravity, unless the program is doing only 1 FPS.  So, assuming you want more fluidity than 1 FPS, consider doing

```
    jumpVar += gravity/fps;
```

However, to get the exact velocity required to lift you to a height, I think the calculation is...

```
    initialVelocityInMetersPerSecond = Math.sqrt( 2 * gravity * metersToJump )
```

So instead of jumpVar = -70, you would do something like...

```
    // get posititive distance since we'll use to get a square root
    var metersToJump:Number = Player.y - platform.y;
    jumpVar = -Math.sqrt( 2 * gravity * metersToJump );
```

...and then in the ENTER_FRAME handler...

```
    Player.y += jumpVar / fps;
    jumpVar += gravity / fps;
```

From your example it's not the case, but if you place the platform below the Player, it won't work as you can't get the root of a negative number!

In my example code I am not fixing the height of the platform, so how you decide on the target platform is a completely separate matter.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have not yet had a chance to test it yet but will tomorrow. I just wanted to thank you for taking the time to reply :) . Although I did notice you had `platform.y - Player.y` does this mean it detects the platforms I have already created. I haven't gotten that far but that would be terrific if it took that in to account...

Comment: No, no detection. I put that there for you to think about creating a platform object. This way you could have multiple platforms of variable height, or simply to encapsulate somewhat the values you currently handle in local logic (i.e., jumpVar = -70, the need for a multi-jump to reach a minimum height, etc.)

Comment: I just noticed I made a mistake in the metersToJump calculation.  It should have been Player.y - platform.y since we need a positive number for Math.sqrt.  I updated my answer with the change.  Note that my examples don't account for the horizontal distance necessary to reach the platform, which is a problem you'll have to consider if you place platforms below the player.  I am also assuming you're not doing a game where a fixed jump height with strategically placed platforms would be an option.