# Flash AS3 Gravity and Jumping

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, gravity

Using ActionScript 3, I'm creating a platformer game on Flash CC. My code works fine, but I'm not satisfied with my character's jump.

I need a parabolic jump so he is able to step on other platforms, but at the moment my character only jumps in a straight motion and falls too fast to the floor. My character should fall slow enough so I can press the left and right buttons while they're falling.

In the below code, I'm using mouse events because I will be publishing it on my mobile device.

My character has an instance name of `SDeer`:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
var xdir: int = 0;
var ydir: int = 0;
var speed: int = 10;
var jumping = false;
var gravity: int = 1.5;
var floor : int = 400;
var LeftUp : Boolean;
var RightUp : Boolean;



SDeer.gotoAndStop ('Still');

RightButton.addEventListener (MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onRight);
JumpButton.addEventListener (MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onJump);
LeftButton.addEventListener (MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onLeft);
LeftButton.addEventListener (MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, LeftOnUp);
RightButton.addEventListener (MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, RightOnUp);
DuckButton.addEventListener (MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onDuck);
addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onUp);
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);

function onRight (e:MouseEvent): void {
    SDeer.gotoAndStop ('Running');
    xdir = 1;
}

function onJump (e:MouseEvent): void {

    if (LeftUp == true){
        SDeer.gotoAndStop ('JumpLeft')
    }

    else {
    SDeer.gotoAndStop ('Jumping');
    }

    ydir = -1;
}

function onDuck (e:MouseEvent): void {

    if (LeftUp == true && RightUp == false){
        SDeer.gotoAndStop ('DuckLeft')
    }

    else if (RightUp == true && LeftUp == false){
    SDeer.gotoAndStop ('Duck');
    }

    ydir = 1;
}

function onUp (e:MouseEvent): void {
    if (LeftUp == true && RightUp == false) {
        SDeer.gotoAndStop ('LeftStill');
    }

    else if (RightUp == true && LeftUp == false){
    SDeer.gotoAndStop ('Still');
    }


    xdir = 0;
    ydir = 0;
}

function onLeft (e:MouseEvent) : void {
    SDeer.gotoAndStop ('RunLeft');
    xdir = -1;
}

function LeftOnUp (e:MouseEvent) : void {
    LeftUp = true;
    RightUp = false;
}

function RightOnUp (e:MouseEvent) : void {
    LeftUp = false;
    RightUp = true;
}



function onEnterFrame(e: Event): void {
  SDeer.x += xdir * speed;
  SDeer.y += ydir * speed;
}

//Hit check
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, hitCheck);
function hitCheck(event: Event): void {

  SDeer.y += gravity;
  if (SDeer.y + SDeer.height / 2 < floor){
  gravity++;
  }

  else {
  gravity = 0;
  SDeer.y = floor - SDeer.height / 2;
  }
}
```

Comment: A general stylistic note - in Actionscript it is convention to use lowercase to start variable names, and uppercase to start class names.  So, you would have something like var sDeer:SDeer = new SDeer();  Also, functions are started with lowercase and don't have spaces between their names and the parameter list parenthesis.  For example, you would write sDeer.gotoAndStop('Still');

Answer (score 1):

Don't reset the gravity.  Instead, have a velocity affected by gravity.  For example...

```
var gravity:Number = 9.8; // meters/second/second standard, but can be whatever
var jumpVel:Number = 0;

function onJump( e:MouseEvent ) : void
{
    if (LeftUp == true){
        SDeer.gotoAndStop ('JumpLeft')
    }
    else {
        SDeer.gotoAndStop ('Jumping');
    }

    jumpVel Number = -20; // 45mph!
}
```

...and in your ENTER_FRAME handler...

```
    if ( jumpVel != 0 )
    {
        SDeer.y += jumpVel / stage.frameRate;
        jumpVel += gravity / stage.frameRate;
        if ( SDeer.y + SDeer.height >= floor )
        {
            jumpVel = 0;
            SDeer.y = floor - SDeer.height;
        }
    }
```

I have a related answer at [ActionScript 3, How to get character to jump for longer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32239461/actionscript-3-how-to-get-character-to-jump-for-longer/32240692#32240692)

Comment: Hi, Joseph! Thanks for taking the time to answer my question. I tried adding your code with mine and it worked but when my character jumped it's falling too slow and when it jumps it seems like it's floating upwards until I press the left or right button. Please help :(

Comment: Hi, I have another problem. When I press my character's duck button, it cannot detect the floor anymore and it continously goes downward. :(

Comment: I suspect a conflict between `SDeer.y += ydir * speed` and the new jumpVel values.  Perhaps `ydir * speed` overwhelms jumpVel.  I'd place some trace statements in the enterFrame function to check on all the values as the character's position changes.  For example, at the beginning of the function, try `trace("BEFORE", sDeer.y, ydir*speed, jumpVel)`, and then at the end of the function, `trace("AFTER", sDeer.y, ydir*speed, jumpVel)`

Comment: Alright. I'll give it a try later. Thanks again, Joseph. I'll update you as soon as I try it. :)

Comment: Hi, Joseph! I tried putting in your code again, here are the values from the trace. "[SWF] AnimalRescue_DeerTrial.swf - 62827 bytes after decompression
BEFORE 346 0 0
AFTER 332.7 0 0
BEFORE 332.7 0 0
AFTER 332.7 0 0
BEFORE 332.7 0 0
AFTER 332.7 0 0"
What does it mean?

Comment: Well, it means you'll need to take a very critical look at how sDeer's coordinates are being changed. You have one approach, which is adjusting by direction * speed, and another, which is adjusting based on gravity. It could be that the "scale" of these changes are too different, that they are cancelling each other out, that the values are being prematurely reset, that they are happening at different times, etc. Certainly someone could find the exact bug, but I strongly encourage you to step line-by-line through your code to find the logical error. Use the debugger to step, you'll learn a lot!

Comment: Hi, Joseph! I tried publishing my game on my gadget and it seems like it's working. I just want to know how I could make my character jump higher.

Comment: Thank you so much for trying to help me with my code!